# Detecting IP Address of someone using 'copy' function

Tags: php, ajax, ip

Is it possible through WordPress (through a plugin, PHP or otherwise) to detect the IP of someone copying (ctrl+c) content on my website, and have that data sent/displayed to an admin?

Appreciate any assistance :)

Comment: Copying content happens after the page and PHP has already ran, detecting copying in javascript is unreliable but wouldn't be a WP question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a road map to do this. You should adjust this code to your exact requirements:

You can detect copy event in JavaScript using this code in your page

```
<script>

   jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
       function myFunction() {
          // here make an ajax call to send data to server
          $.ajax({
              url: "http://yourwebsite.com",
              type: 'POST',
              data: {'copied': true}
          });
      }
   });

</script>
```

and replacing `<body>` tag of the page to something like this

```
<body oncopy="myFunction()">
```

**Note:** The `oncopy` event may not work as expected in some browsers when trying to copy an *image*.

On server side yo can easily get IP  of someone copying content on your website, and have that data saved somewhere for display.

```
function ajax_callback_function( ) {

    if ( isset($_POST['copied']) ) {

        $User_IP   = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // Get User IP

        // Here goes the code to save $User_IP somewhere in db
        ....
        ....

    }

    return "";
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Apologies for this being off topic.

Comment: @distinctly Stay blessed. Please click on up arrow for "This answer is useful" so it may help someone finding code like this.